# I need to model a document visually and then generate some POCO, EF designer or Class diagram?

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I need to model a document which I will be persisting as XML. In the first instance I will be creating some POCO classes for use as View Models. I know that I could generate them via EF designer/T4. However I wonder whether this is the correct route since what I am actually trying to do is model a document and its contents which will then map across to an XML document and ultimately a schema if required.

I want to use the POCO VMs to provide strongly typed views and also to enable data annotations for validation etc. I can then serialise the data back to XML.

So what would be the best way to model and generate these POCOs please?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure how EF will help you with serializing Xml? If you want to generate POCOs you need to have something to generate POCOs from. What it would be? EF Model? Is EF model suitable for what you need at all? For serialization you can use Linq to Xml. Potentially you could implement IXmlSerializable but it is **a lot** of work with XmlReader and XmlWriter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. No I do not need EF to serialize the data. I use SharpSerializer for that. However it does need the Class definitions to create the Create the XML and also to deserialize from. So I was looking for a quick method to create these classes. EF designer can generate POCO classes via the Powerpack(from ModelFirst design in VS 20120) using T4. I could then use these as the ViewModel classes, but I am not sure that the EF designer is the correct designer to use since I am not creating tables for these entities.

Comment: I don't think EF Designer will be useful here. It will be more work to draw all the boxes and add all the properties then coding it by hand. Why do you want your classes to be generated instead of just coded manually? It seems to add one more layer of complexity and may have no benefits...

Comment: Pawel, I think I am coming to the same conclusion, having played with it for the last half hour. Also all the classes are seperate. So I think it will be easier to model straight in XML. I believe I can only generate a class from an XSD, but I am still looking. However there are tools to create XSDs from XML like XSD.exe and websites. I did a double take on your name as a "Pawel" also wrote SharpSerialiser, but it is a different "Pawel" ! Many thanks.

Comment: I did not mentrion Xsd.exe before since it does not generate POCO. No, I am not the SharpSeriliser guy.

Comment: I am now experimenting with XML->XSD, XSD -> C# via XSD2Code. The generated classes are pretty good, although I had a naive thought that I might be able to get a nested class, rather than multiple classes for different elements.... I digress a little. If you want to put an answer in then I will mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think EF Designer will be useful here. It will be more work to draw all the boxes and add all the properties then coding it by hand. Why do you want your classes to be generated instead of just coded manually? It seems to add one more layer of complexity and may have no benefits... You could try using xsd.exe but the code it will generate will be heavily attributed (so no POCO).